# Refresh page or call JS function after New Item dialog closes

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a link when clicked, shows the New Item dialog. When the user clicks 'Save', the list item is added. Is there a way to attach the dialog's onClose event to another piece of code? Or can I somehow listen for when this dialog closes and refresh the page (so the new item shows in my custom list view)?

Here is the link that opens the dialog:

```
<a href=\"javascript:OpenPopUpPage('/site/Lists/ListName/NewForm.aspx?IsDlg=1'>New Item</a>
```

Comment: To simply refresh the parent page after the modal dialog closes, add "RefreshPage" to the end of your call. Ex - javascript:OpenPopUpPage('/site/index.aspx', RefreshPage);

Answer (score 4):

You can use SharePoint `SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage(url, callback, width, height)` Method and set callback function that runs when the modal dialog is closed.

**Parameters**

1. url Type: String The URL of the page to be shown in the modal
   dialog.
2. **callback Type: function pointer The callback function that runs when the modal dialog is closed.**
3. width Type: int The width of the modal dialog.
4. height Type: int The height of the modal dialog.

[Link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410825%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Just a note, OP could probably just keep using the same function and the second argument for the redirect. e.g., `OpenPopUpPage('...',function(saved){window.location='...'})`

Comment: Both tested and working! Erik, you saved me some overhead by providing the simplest sln .. ty

Comment: That's great @Colbs. I'll let Andrey update his answer accordingly and he will have my vote :)